# Weird behaviour print if code is written in extra function

Tags: c, function, printf, contiki

it was difficult for me to describe the problem in the title but I try it here. I have some variables and I use printf to print them. Then I assign a second variable and also print it. Everything works as aspected. When I try to push the first lines including the first printf into a function the printf adds a random letter to the second printf. Example below:
Version 1 (works as aspected):

```
main(){
uint8_t len = strlen( (char *)packetbuf_dataptr() );

int16_t channel = packetbuf_attr(PACKETBUF_ATTR_CHANNEL);//or  integer     value=1
int16_t network_id = packetbuf_attr(PACKETBUF_ATTR_NETWORK_ID);//or  integer value=2
int16_t link_quality = packetbuf_attr(PACKETBUF_ATTR_LINK_QUALITY);//or  integer value=3
printf("Main: %d, %d, %d ", channel, network_id, link_quality);
print_message(len);
}
void print_message(uint8_t len){
    char message_v[len];
    packetbuf_copyto(message_v);
    printf("Message: %s\r\n", message_v);
}
```

Result:

> Main: 146, 0, 108 Message: Earth

Second Version (nearly the same but an extra function)

```
main(){
uint8_t len = strlen( (char *)packetbuf_dataptr() );
print_variables();
print_message(len);
}

void print_message(uint8_t len){
    char message_v[len];
    packetbuf_copyto(message_v);
    printf("Message: %s\r\n", message_v);
}    

void print_variables(){
int16_t channel = packetbuf_attr(PACKETBUF_ATTR_CHANNEL);//or  integer value=1
int16_t network_id = packetbuf_attr(PACKETBUF_ATTR_NETWORK_ID);//or  integer value=2
int16_t link_quality = packetbuf_attr(PACKETBUF_ATTR_LINK_QUALITY);//or  integer value=3
printf("Main: %d, %d, %d ", channel, network_id, link_quality);
}
```

Result:

> Main: 146, 0, 108 Message: Earth z

Comment: Is the data in the buffer null-terminated?

Comment: Do you have prototypes before calling functions the compiler has not yet seen? To answer this, please make a [mcve]. This is especially interesting because `print_message(uint8_t len)` is defined with a parameter, but called without...

Comment: @EugeneSh. yeah, I would bet Jon Skeet's rep on this being a NUL terminator issue, either rmissing, or not enough space allocated.

Comment: Plus, I just noticed 'strlen' in network code.  That rarely ends well.

Comment: @MartinJames Woah. Wasn't aware of rep millionaires existence.

Comment: @Yunnosch : I fixed this
All others: The buffer is from contiki, sooo I guess yes? But I am not sure

Comment: `message_v` is having allocated one byte less(at least) than needed. From [contiki docs](https://dak664.github.io/contiki-doxygen/a01563.html#gacad3b92ca8f9ce7845b6c490ba9f05bf): *The external buffer to which the packetbuf is to be copied must be able to accomodate at least (PACKETBUF_SIZE + PACKETBUF_HDR_SIZE) bytes.*

Comment: @EugeneSh. oh good, I don't have to pay out:)

Comment: There's a pretty dire need for proper indentation here. Not only does indentation communicate structure, it communicates intent, something that helps identify bugs.

Comment: neither of the posted code samples compiles!  Amongst other things, they are missing the needed `#include` statements for the needed header files.  Also, the function: `main()` ALWAYS has a return type of `int`

Comment: @user3629249 : I tried to simplify all code otherwise it would be very long. Today I will try some of the guesses the made here. Otherwise I will have to write all code copied

Comment: `packetbuf_copyto` does not add a terminating zero character. Hence, this is an example of undefined behavior.